# Don't automatically open the folder of mounted devices

Tags: usb, nautilus, mount, automount

I usually charge my phone through a USB connection. Due to Ubuntu 13.04 detecting and mounting it, Nautlius automatically opens the mounted folder. Can I stop Nautlius from automatically opening the folder of some mounted devices?

Comment: On Xubuntu, I do `xfconf-query -c thunar-volman -p /automount-drives-enabled -s false` but I heavily suspect it won't work in "plain" Ubuntu, because this command recalls XFCE and Thunar.

Comment: It's `automount-drives/enabled`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click on `Applications`->`System Tools`->`dconf Editor`

In the window which opens, Select `org` from the side bar, then `gnome` and then `desktop` and then `media-handling` Uncheck the `automount-open` from the right side bar.

See the picture.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But can I also change it for one device only?

Comment: worth noting that you have to do this as the user you're logged in as, not neccessarily root

Comment: You're a life saver!

Comment: @MeinAccount – someone at least ‘solved’ this by [id-speficic unmount scripts...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301122/prevent-a-specific-usb-device-from-auto-mounting)

Answer (score 3):

Install Ubuntu Tweak. Open it up. Go to `Tweaks` -> `File Manager` and you'll see the option there.