# Prevent a specific USB device from auto-mounting

Tags: mount, automount, udev, unmount, udisks

I want to stop a USB device from automounting in Ubuntu 13.04. For example, when I connect my iPhone 5 to my desktop I am consistently prompted for what I want to do (whether or not I want to erase the "iPod" connected to my machine, etc). Since I don't use the computer as anything more than a way to charge the device, is there a way to prevent the device from mounting and still allow the device to draw current from the machine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Using the terminal and gedit

First find the ID for your device from a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using `lsusb` when your device is connected (eg `0951:1692`). Also you should to find what is the name of your device with `lsblk`. Let say the name is `/dev/sdb1`.

Create a new script, let say `unmount.sh` in `/lib/udev` with `sudo -H gedit /lib/udev/unmount.sh` and put next lines inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

Save the file, close it and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x /lib/udev/unmount.sh
```

Now, you must to make a new rule file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with `sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/100-unmount-iphone.rules`and put a new rule in there like this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1692", RUN+="/lib/udev/unmount.sh"
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

To reload udev rules without restart, use next command:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

### Using Cuttlefish

Or, another way is to install and use [Cuttlefish [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cuttlefish/) - a simple tool that realises reflexes on your computer.

Comment: Oh well, looks like Cuttlefish is no longer available

Comment: I have installed Cuttlefisth just now on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: used `udisksctl` in `unmount.sh` to unmount a Windows partition from a USB flash drive: `udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sr1`. for reference: http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisksctl.1.html

Comment: For those without `udisks`, you can also use `umount /dev/sdb1` to unmount the drive and `eject /dev/sdb` to detach it (it will no longer show up on the sidebar of the file browser). This can also be done by UUID instead (`umount /dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>`), in case having other USB devices plugged in changes the device name (i.e. `/dev/sdb` becomes `/dev/sdc`)

Comment: Came here to do this for my iPhone. In that case a one-liner rules.d seems to work. Create the file: `sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/100-unmount-iphone.rules`. Add this line: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="iPhone", RUN+="/usr/bin/killall -s SIGINT /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-afc"`. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/581810/iphone-does-not-unmount-properly-when-unplugged

Answer (score 0):

To control which programs automatically start when you plug in a device, go to

> System-Settings - Details - Removable Media

[image]

Source: [Ubuntu Documentation - Mount/USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB)