# Prevent auto mounting a device in 14.10

Tags: usb, laptop, automount, 14.10, smartphone

Now i know that there is an answer out there at [Prevent a specific USB device from auto-mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301122/prevent-a-specific-usb-device-from-auto-mounting) for 13.04. But there isn't enough specificity in the accepted answer for what i am looking for.

My problem is sometimes I charge my android phone from my laptop when on the go sometimes. But i run into problems when a mp3 looking device( when under MTP on phone) or two (one for sd card one for device mem) camera devices(when under PTP on phone) pop up on my launcher. Also I often get like 30-50 pop ups saying "Samsung phone cannot be mounted" with a description of the port and usb number. Each popup ending up being a different port but the same usb number (cause im not unplugging my phone, it just pops up another pop up underneath the current one, which i don't notice right away because it doesn't go to the front of my windows, it goes to the background.

My question is , I want to stop auto mounting, but the link i gave shows an answer that I think will work, but I want to still be able to mount my phone if I select to mount manually. Any one know of a way to stop auto mounting and still be able to mount a device by manually mounting it?