# Can automatically mounted camera be automatically unmounted by script in 14.04

Tags: camera, unmount

The version of Ubuntu I have (14.04.1) automatically mounts my digital camera and generates a box inviting me to say what to do with it.  Since I was dissatisfied with all the options presented, I wrote a script which does exactly what I want, using gphoto2 to access the camera and get files from it.  The one problem is that, even if I have specified 'do nothing' to the box, the camera remains mounted and thus, as far as gphoto2 is concerned, unavailable because not released.  In order to release it I must open or find a folder display, and specifically eject the camera.  I would rather not bother with this step and just let my script run.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this.

Comment: It's possible using udev rules: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301122/prevent-a-specific-usb-device-from-auto-mounting

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04, and up, you'll need to use the utility `gio` (which replaced `gvfs-mount`).

If the camera is mounted and you have gphoto2 installed, try

```
gio mount -s gphoto2
```

but if you want to target the camera specifically:

```
gio mount -l
```

will show you the mountable drives.

If you have a camera plugged in, it might look like this:

```
$ gio mount -l
Drive(0): DA4032
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(0): Canon Digital Camera
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
  Mount(0): Canon Digital Camera -> gphoto2://%5Busb%3A002,002%5D/
    Type: GProxyShadowMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
Mount(1): Canon Digital Camera -> gphoto2://%5Busb%3A002,002%5D/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

copying the location after the `->` will allow you to unmount it via `gio mount -u` (unmount, if you look at the help: `gio help mount`

```
gio mount -u gphoto2://%5Busb%3A002,002%5D/
```

will unmount the camera via shell. Now, to automate this, you'll need to create a systemd script.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to fiddle with `udev` (which is a system thing), you can use the `udisk` interface to unmount the camera.

The camera will normally mount at a fixed place, like `/media/user/1234-5678/` or similar (YMMV, depends on how the camera formats the card); and as a device, say `/dev/sdc1/`.

Now, you can unmount it from your script using

```
 udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc1
```

the problem is that the device can change; my solution is having this little magic

```
 udisksctl unmount -b $(mount | grep 1234-5678  | cut -d" "  -f1)
```

which will work provided that the card id doesn't change.

Comment: The camera (a Nikon Coolpix p90) is being connected via PTP.  As a result it does not appear mounted on anything in /media, nor does it appear in mtab.  This is a feature introduced with 14.04, I believe.  In earlier versions of 14.04, many digital cameras could not be connected.  The present arrangement seems to be patch.  In order to 'release' the camera from gphoto2's point of view, I have to ask for a folder to be opened (that is, directory contents displayed in a window) and then 'eject' it.  There is no obvious command-line way to do this.