# iPhone does not unmount properly when unplugged

Tags: udev, iphone, umount

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on my netbook, and connect my iPhone via USB cable so that it tethers and I can access the internet.  This all works as expected.

The issue is that when the iPhone is unplugged from the USB cable, it doesn't unmount properly, so when the iPhone is next plugged in, a message box appears with the following text:

**Unable to mount iPhone**
Location is already mounted

Unplugging and replugging my iPhone throughout the day results in lots of these message boxes appearing.

The output of `mount` when the iPhone is plugged in includes the following:

```
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse
```

This line is still there after the iPhone is unplugged.  If I manually umount that location, then the message does NOT appear when the iPhone is next plugged in:

```
sudo umount /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Is there any way (maybe through udev) to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to automate this.  The issue was that `gvfs-mount -l` still showed a mount (`afc://<iPhone_serial_number>/`) even after the iPhone had been unplugged.  It was this mount that triggered the *Unable to mount iPhone* message when the iPhone was plugged back in.  This mount was provided by the `gvfsd-afc` gvfs backend. Killing `gvfsd-afc` removes the mount.

To make `udev` do this automatically when the iPhone is unplugged, create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-iphone-umount.rules` and add the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="iPhone", RUN+="/usr/bin/killall -s SIGINT /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-afc"
```

Then run `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` to get udev to load the new rule.