# Disable usb automount for all users

Tags: unity, gnome, usb, mount, automount

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with LTSP.  I am using usbmount to mount usb thumbdrives outside of the desktop which works great.  The problem is that when a user is logged into the desktop and connects a thumbdrive they are shown an error alert box similar to

```
"Unable to mount Lexar.  Device /dev/sda1 is already mounted at '/media/usb0'.
```

I've been able to stop the issue for the logged in user account with gsettings.  How can I achieve

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

for all users from the command line?

I've tried a udev rule like suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85061/automount-not-disabling-in-ubuntu-12-04-or-13-04#85078) but that did not fix the issue

---

### update #1

So I tried using Upstart Session jobs without any luck.

```
$ cat /usr/share/upstart/sessions/ltsp-replace-usb-automount-with-usbmount.conf
description "disable default automounting because it displays error boxes to the end user"
start on desktop-session-start
script
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
end script
```

and also

```
$ cat /usr/share/upstart/sessions/ltsp-replace-usb-automount-with-usbmount.conf
description "disable default automounting because it displays error boxes to the end user"
start on desktop-start
script
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
end script
```

I cannot find any indication the jobs actually ran.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem with what feels like a dirty hack.  If anyone can provide a better answer, please share.  Otherwise I am going to mark this as the correct answer eventually.

Create an autostart launcher for the desktop that runs gsettings.  Example as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/xdg/autostart/gsettings-for-all-users.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=gsettings For All Users
Exec=gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
Icon=system-run
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Reference:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon
2. http://xmodulo.com/how-to-automatically-run-script-when-logging-into-ubuntu-desktop.html

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/301133/367165

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but after looking that over I do not think it achieves what I am trying to do.  I need the fix to work with arbitrary thumbdrives.  I did try using a udev rule linked to in the top question but couldn't get it to work.  My problem is that the desktop tries to automount the user's usb stick a second time after I have already mounted it with a script in the background.  This second attempt causes the desktop to display an error to the user.  I just want to stop the second mount attempt by the desktop.

Comment: I think your idea is not bad +1.

Comment: However, it can be easily circumvented.