# Disable auto-mount of *only* Camera SDCard on USB connection

Tags: usb, automount, camera

I have a question regarding the auto-mounting of my Nikon camera.
When the camera is connected via USB the memory card of the camera is mounted and displays as a drive on the task bar. This causes conflict with tethering programs that need to take control of the camera. I can disable auto-mounting altogether using dconf, but it is a pain to keep turning it on and off all the time. How can just disable the behaviour for this camera alone and nothing else?
Thanks in advance :)﻿

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your device is `/dev/sdb1`. Using `lsusb` get the ID of your device (it will be something like 0651:1722 or whatever)

Create a script called script.sh in `/lib/udev` (you may have to use `sudo` while creating the file) and put the following lines in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

Save it and make it executable with:

> `chmod +x /lib/udev/script.sh`

Make a udev rule file called `100-unmount-SDcard.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`  (again you should use `sudo` to create this file) and populate it with:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="<your-id>", ATTRS{idProduct}=="<your-id>", RUN+="/lib/udev/script.sh"
```

Save the file and run:

> `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

For more options see [Prevent a specific USB device from auto-mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301122/prevent-a-specific-usb-device-from-auto-mounting)