# Disable automount for one particular drive

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I know how to disable automount for all drives.

But I want to disable automount for one particular drive only.

How to do this?

Version: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Possibly related to / duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/301122/prevent-a-specific-usb-device-from-auto-mounting

Comment: Can you include the contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output from `lsblk -o 
 NAME,TYPE,LABEL,UUID` in your question?